# Issue with Y-axis labels (not completely visible)

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have a problem with Y-axis labels: they are not completely visible. But when I scroll `RecyclerView` out of screen and back they become visible again. Is there a way to control visibility of these labels?

[image][image]

Comment: post the code of your adapter and adapter items.

Comment: [see this fragment](https://github.com/ilyarudyak/Portfel/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/ilyarudyak/android/portfel/ui/MarketFragment.java). Upon first installation of an app everything is OK. But when switching to other tabs and back grid can become invisible. After click grid become visible but labels will be partly  invisible. If we add animation on X axis sometimes (not always) labels are corrupted even on first install. And so on.

Comment: Have you tried calling invalidate() on the chart afer filling it with data?